# Restric firestore CRUD to users within a specific domain

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a rule in Firestore that restricts usage to all CRUD operations for users that belongs to a specific domain, My issue is that seems like contains clause doesn't exist in the rule context.

this is my rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isUserAndSignedIn();
    }
  }

  function isUserAndSignedIn(){
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email.contains('domain.com')
  }
}
```

the error I'm getting is:
Error: simulator.rules line [9], column [36]. Function not found error: Name: [contains].

I also tried with indexOf like

> request.auth.token.email.indexOf('domain.com')!=-1
>   request.auth.token.email.endsWith('domain.com')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.auth.token.email` is going to be a String, and [according to the reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String), String doesn't have a method called "contains".  It does have a method called [`matches`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String) for using regular expressions, and you can see the documentation has a handy bit of sample code:

```
'user@domain.com'.matches('.*@domain[.]com') == true
```

Which you should be able to adapt to your case:

```
return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email.matches('.*@domain[.]com')
```

Comment: I was looking at the exact documentation right now, I figured the same approach thanks!